# CSS/SCSS only works as an inline style in the div, and does not work if I use a class or an id

Tags: css, sass

I have many imported SCSS files for third party plugins which could be the problem, but essentially if I directly use the `style` attribute (inline style) in the div the intended behavior works. But, if I create a class or even an ID it does not apply to it.

Any suggestions on what to look into or immediate corrections would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="box" style="margin-left: 50px; margin-right: 50px">
  <div class="padded" >
    <%= @step.description %>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when I change the above code to below, and add class to custom.css.scss - it does not work:

```
<div class="box description">
  <div class="padded" >

   <%= @step.description %>
  </div>
</div>

 .description {

    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px
}
```

Comment: Check if your css file is being loaded into your page, make sure that it is included on your page first.  If  you have it included fire up fiddler and check for 404 (red) errors.  I do this all the time.

Comment: Is the Sass compiling to CSS properly?  Are you referencing the compiled CSS file correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that `.description` is not specific enough to override any pre-existing CSS rules that specify the margin settings for the `.box .padded` container `div`.

You might try something like:

```
.box.description {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px
}
```

or if the specificity is stubbornly high, try:

```
<div id="thisbox" class="box description">
  <div class="padded" >
    <%= @step.description %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and adjust the CSS as follows:

```
div#thisbox.box.description {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px
}
```

(See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/AvRXT/)

The reason your style rule worked as an inline style is that inline styles have a higher precedence than any CSS rules in external style sheets.

**PS**

I have assumed that you added your CSS rule to a pre-existing CSS/SCSS style sheet or else coded it correctly as an embedded style using the `<style>` tag in the `<head>` section of the document.  See post by [jmeas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386415/css-scss-only-works-if-i-directly-type-style-in-the-div-and-does-not-work-if-i/18386457#18386457)

Comment: Hah, this is probably the issue. After reading this, I'm sure my answer couldn't actually be his problem.

Comment: @jmeas Actually, both problems could co-exist so your answer is relevant, which is why I cross-referenced it!

Comment: Yes I am adding to a pre-existing SCSS stylesheet.  This, to me, is definitely the problem, however I tried the two examples you gave and it still does not work; meaning it is not going down to the level of specificity I need to override existing rules. I even tried it with an ID, which I thought was the most specific of all.

Comment: We would need to look at the style sheet live to find the issue.  There may be other selectors or `!important` flags in the imported style sheets.  Can you post a link?

Comment: By the way, is `.box` being floated or absolutely positioned (as in an image rotator?)

Comment: An inline style may be the solution in this case.  Though not ideal, it may be necessary.

Comment: By the way, I did update my answer with an `id` attribute that might help.

Comment: Your new solution makes sense, but does not work for me, and you are probably right in that it stems from a lot of obscure important! tags.  I am going to have to remove them at a later time, but for now go with the inline.  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

It might be that you need to put the styling within the [style element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style).

```
<style>
.description {
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-right: 50px
}
</style>
```

And here's some more things you might need to know about the style element:

The style attribute has a `type` attribute that you might see some websites include. Valid values for this attribute are MIME types. For instance, `<style type="text/css">`. The [w3c specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) require browsers to default the value to `text/css`, so omitting it should be (and, as far as I know, is) fine.

For now, you should only place style elements in the `<head>` of the document, which is where the specs require them be at the moment.

However, [in the near future](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-style-element) we will be able to scope stylesheets. Scoped sheets can be placed inline in the document and have a `scoped` attribute set to `true` on the element. [Read more introductory material on scoping here at the MDN.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the priority of your CSS high by using **`!important`**. For example, I was using material cards and `card-image` class was overriding my CSS so I set it as important.

```
.project_7_bg {height:250px !important;
               object-fit: cover ;  
             background-color :#408C54}
```